# is this theorem true for case quasi-projective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, affine-geometry

Definition. If $X, Y$ are two varieties, a morphism $\varphi: X \rightarrow Y$
is a continuous map such that for every open set $V \subseteq Y,$ and for every regular function $f: V \rightarrow k$, the function $\varphi^{*} := f \circ \varphi: \varphi^{-1}(V) \rightarrow k$ is regular.

let $O(Y)$ be the ring of all regular
functions on $Y$.

> Theorem .Let $X$ be a variety
> and $Y \subset \mathbb{A}^{n}$ be Affine
> variete and $\varphi: X \rightarrow Y$
> be set function ( or any subset of $X$ send to a subset of $Y$)
> then:
> $\varphi$ is a morphism iff
> $\varphi^{*}$ send $O(Y)$ to $O(X)$ .

> Is above theorem true when $Y$ be quasi-projective ?

Comment: Huh?  "$\varphi\colon X\to Y$ be a set function" and $\varphi^*$ don't make much sense (unless you are already taking the scheme-theoretic view that elements of $X$ are prime ideals of some polynomial ring so are sets, in which case $\varphi$ being a set function doesn't add anything).

Comment: I don't agree. You could define $\varphi^*(f)=f\circ \varphi$, and then I think this would make sense.

Answer (score 2):

No; the problem is that $O(Y)$ could be very small.  For instance, if $Y$ is an irreducible projective variety, then $O(Y)$ will consist of only constant functions, so $\varphi^*$ will always send $O(Y)$ to $O(X)$ (since $O(X)$ always includes the constant functions), no matter what $\varphi$ is.

Comment: What is simplest example of irreducible projective variety ? and how $O(Y)$ in this case is exactly constant function?

Comment: just consider $P^1$ in this case it is easy to see that the only regular functions are constant one. for this you should choose a definition for projective space. for example if you define it as the variety obtained from gluing two affine line together(one without 0 and one without $\infty$) then you understand that  any regular function on $P^1$ is given by two polynomial $f,g$ such that $f(t)=g(1/t)$ which means that $f=g=constant$.